# html5 canvas visualize cluster

Tags: html, canvas, cluster-analysis

I have a set of points in my canvas element. Say, something like this:

[image]

I am dealing with clustering and all that points belong to one cluster. So I have to somehow connect them. What might be the idea of connecting them? I mean, I cannont just draw lines between all poits, I have to somehow select points which will form bounds of cluster. I just want to do it more user friendly. Maybe one solution could be to find minimum spanning tree and visualize it? What can you suggest? Question is not about the implementation details, but about the idea how do to that.

Comment: Perhaps you looking for something like http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045

Comment: Good point, but no. There one have also manually detect which points are connected.

Answer (score 1):

**Here's how to calculate the bounding box of random circles:**

```js
// canvas related variables
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

// the radius of each circle
var radius=4;

// generate 4 random points
var points=[];
for(var i=0;i<4;i++){
  var randomX=Math.max(radius,Math.min(cw,Math.random()*cw-radius));
  var randomY=Math.max(radius,Math.min(ch,Math.random()*ch-radius));   
  points.push({x:randomX,y:randomY});
}

// vars to hold the top-left & bottom-right points of the cluster's bounding box
var minX=1000000;
var minY=minX;
var maxX=-100000;
var maxY=maxX;

// calc the bounding box
for(var i=0;i<points.length;i++){

  var p=points[i];

  // calc the top-left & bottom-right of this circle's bounding box
  var xleft=p.x-radius;
  var xright=p.x+radius;
  var ytop=p.y-radius;
  var ybottom=p.y+radius;

  // expand the cluster's bounding box based on this circle's bounding box
  if(xleft<minX){minX=xleft;}
  if(xright>maxX){maxX=xright;}
  if(ytop<minY){minY=ytop;}
  if(ybottom>maxY){maxY=ybottom;}

  // draw this point
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(p.x,p.y,radius,0,Math.PI*2);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();

}

// draw the cluster's bounding box
var width=maxX-minX;
var height=maxY-minY;
ctx.strokeRect(minX,minY,width,height);
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; padding:10px; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```